# Translation of Terms and Conditions

Tags: civievent, translation

The wording of the GDPR texts is translated (into Dutch), but the title still says "Terms and Conditions". Where to find the string to translate? Or how can it be translated? Please include a translation in next releases. It's odd on an event registration in local language to speak about "Terms and Conditions"!

Answer (score 3):

As a quick fix, you can use the word replacement feature of CiviCRM, which is located in the admin section. Just note that the character '&' is encoded as a html special character. Therefore the original English string you want to replace is `Terms &amp; Conditions`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Use backticks (``) around special characters if you want it to not get escaped by stackexchange, e.g. `&amp;` (https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Just improved the answer.

Comment: @Joachim, I know the function and I have used it successfully. But I am looking without success for the translation strings of the GPDR module.

Answer (score 3):

Currently the string in question isn't properly translated into Dutch.

CiviCRM's translation project(s) live on Transifex. There are two "teams" (to use Transifex's nomenclature!) for translation.

These are:

- [CiviCRM/CiviCRM](https://www.transifex.com/civicrm/civicrm) - Core Translations
- [CiviCRM/CiviCRM_Extensions](https://www.transifex.com/civicrm/civicrm_extensions) - Extension Translations

Within each "team" the translations are broken down into "resources" - groups of strings. For core these are functional areas of the software. For extensions it's a single resource per extension.

The GDPR extension is setup on Transifex for translation under the extensions team and having checked there is some progress that could be made to achieve a more complete translation into Dutch.

Simply register on Transifex and use their somewhat clunky UI to translate the strings - then they will be automatically built into .mo files by a nightly job and will soon be available to use in CiviCRM.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Op 3 juli is de vertaling naar het Nederlands van de GDPR-extensie op Transifex afgerond.